# Using CssSelector in Laravel 4

Tags: symfony, laravel, laravel-4

I want to use [CssSelector](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/42/parsing-xml-documents-with-css-selectors) with my Laravel 4 application, I did not install the class because Laravel seem to already have it in this folder :

> /vendor/symfony/css-selector/Symfony/Component/CssSelector

So I tried to use this demo code [from the doc](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/42/parsing-xml-documents-with-css-selectors) :

```
use Symfony\Component\CssSelector\Parser;

$document = new \DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTMLFile('http://fabien.potencier.org/articles');

$xpath = new \DOMXPath($document);
foreach ($xpath->query(Parser::cssToXpath('div.item > h4 > a')) as $node)
{
  printf("%s (%s)\n", $node->nodeValue, $node->getAttribute('href'));
}
```

But i get this error :

> Class 'Symfony\Component\CssSelector\Parser' not found

So my question is, how can i use CssSelector / this class with Laravel ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using Class that doesn't exist. It's not

```
use Symfony\Component\CssSelector\Parser;
```

It's

```
use Symfony\Component\CssSelector\CssSelector;
```

Example usage of CssSelector in `routes.php`

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\CssSelector\CssSelector;

Route::get('test', function() {
    echo "<h3>Hello</h3>";
    print CssSelector::toXPath('h3');
});
```

Read more about [CssSelector here](https://github.com/symfony/CssSelector)

Comment: Its working thank you, I get confuse with namespace.